# why there is a space above and below the svg icons when measured in percentage use? but not when measured in pixels use

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using icons with svg sprites, and I want to have the icon with a width in porcentage, but when I use % in width the icon earn a space on top and bottom.

this is a demo of the problem: http://codepen.io/luisco/pen/GjOaEP?editors=1100

```
 /* I want to achieve the first svg (without space on top and bottom) but in porcentage */

.instagram1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.instagram2 {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%; /* You can omit this rule */
    border: 1px solid black; /* only for show you the space */
}
```

Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your "path"  declaration,the "Move To" command "M" is absolute coordinate representation.

To make "%" to work in CSS, try your path with relative coordinates.